# Рекламный вирус в Windows 8 не дает скачать/запустить антивирус

Tags: windows, malware

У меня в комп скачались обычные рекламные вирусы. Сейчас хочу удалить их с программой advcleaner, но как только пишу ее название в гугле, автоматически закрывает браузер. Скачал через телефон, переместил в ПК, как только открываю - сразу закрывает. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вижу три направления решения.

1. Загрузиться в безопасном режиме и запустить антивирус.
2. Использовать другой антивирус (возможно какой-то сможет справиться с заразой).
3. Скачать загрузочный диск с антивирусом и через загрузку с него удалить вирус.

Ну и напоследок скажу, что лучше не доводить компьютер до вирусов и заранее до возможного появления вируса поставить антивирус. Сейчас есть бесплатные версии, например Avast Free или Kasperskiy Free.

Comment: Хотелось бы поподробнее о вирусе от пострадавшего.

Comment: Разобрались, через HitmanPro получилось

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Но остался ошибка такая, Windows перезагружается постоянно, пишет есть ошибка какая-то. Может знаете в чем дело?

Comment: "есть ошибка какая-то. Может знаете в чем дело?" Пока ошибка "какая-то", то и дело будет "в чем-то".